# How to find out timezone of specific datetime in specific location?

Tags: php, timezone

I have dates of events in another country which I need to save in database. Problem is that those dates have no timezone information included.

Timezone used in this location is CET (standard time) or CEST (summer time).

What is the easiest way to detect which one is in play?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do this. When we set the clock back an hour, for each time in that hour, there's a time in standard time and a time in summer time that would appear the same without a time zone included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking. I *think* what you need to find out is whether a particular date is in daylight savings or not.  If so, you can use `date('I')`.

```
$dst_now = date('I'); // whether our current timezone is currently in DST
$dst_then = date('I', strtotime($date)); // whether that date is in DST for our current timezone

$date_obj = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
$dst_thereandthen = $date_obj->format('I');
// whether that date is in DST for that timezone
```

If what you need is none of these, please clarify what you do need...

Comment: OK, title was a bit misleading. Fixed. However you answer does help as this code can supply timezone info which is what i really need.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume the date_default_timezone_get() function would give you the information you want, though I'm not completely sure it can differentiate between the standard/summer time.

[date_default_timezone_get()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)